# How to set IsOpen property of Fluent.Ribbon StartScreen from ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribboncontrolslibrary

I'm working on a WPF application using the `Fluent.Ribbon` library, and I'm facing an issue with setting the `IsOpen` property of the `StartScreen` control from my view model.
I have a `MainViewModel` that is set as the `DataContext` of my `MainWindow`, and I want to be able to control the visibility of the `StartScreen` from the view model.
Here's how my XAML looks:

```xml
<Fluent:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <!-- Start Screen -->
    <Fluent:Ribbon.StartScreen IsOpen="{Binding IsStartScreenOpen}" />
    <!-- Other ribbon content -->
</Fluent:Ribbon>
```

And here's the relevant property in my `MainViewModel`:

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isStartScreenOpen;

    public bool IsStartScreenOpen
    {
        get { return _isStartScreenOpen; }
        set
        {
            if (_isStartScreenOpen != value)
            {
                _isStartScreenOpen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsStartScreenOpen));
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

However, setting the `IsStartScreenOpen` property in my view model doesn't seem to update the visibility of the `StartScreen` control.

What am I missing? How can I properly set the `IsOpen` property of the `StartScreen` from my view model?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application?

Comment: This is really not enough context. Only showing the binding declaration on a disconnected element and a plain property is pretty much useless in terms of code review. You must add all the relevant context to your question. Your binding is syntactically correct, so it's the property. There is nothing more to say based on what you have shown.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon/blob/develop/Fluent.Ribbon/Controls/Backstage.cs#L57) you can find the `IsOpen` property declaration. There is no specific mode set, so you can try setting `Mode=TwoWay`, just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML markup is invalid and won't compile.

You should bind the property on the actual `StartScreen` element, e.g.:

```
<Fluent:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Fluent:Ribbon.StartScreen>
        <Fluent:StartScreen IsOpen="{Binding IsStartScreenOpen}">
            ...
        </Fluent:StartScreen>
    </Fluent:Ribbon.StartScreen>
</Fluent:Ribbon>
```